# Implement select/deselect item along with toggle all on div container using Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

I am trying to mimic something similar to http://circular.io/ where you can selected an twitter account and deselect account on dashboard. I wanted to know how would you accomplish same behaviour on Angular ? Also I want to have a ability where on click of button I want to select all item (and also have ability to remove specific item from that selected list).

Help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: @desbo So far I tried this out http://jsfiddle.net/9qLm4/1/. Similar concept, but now problem is I can't toggle all and select all in here. Plus after doing selected all I don't have ability to deselect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add a function to your scope to iterate over your items and select/deselect.

```
    $scope.toggleAll = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
            $scope.items[i].selected = !$scope.items[i].selected;
        }
    }
```

You can assign this function to ng-click on an element in your view.

http://jsfiddle.net/9qLm4/16/

I'd recommend using a factory to hold your items, and add the toggle function there.

Comment: Like your answer. But I also found out this kool directive https://github.com/jtrussell/angular-selection-model which is also very helful.